# PHP variable usage in different file

Tags: php, wordpress

here I am again, had before more complicated issue, but now got another (smaller I think).

In template file there's variables in use as "author_id", "authlink", but in controller file doesn't getting author url (but it should).

In template file there's defined variables as authlink and author_id.
Also, in controller file I've included file path where is these variables in use.

```
<?php

set_include_path(".:/domains/example.com/public_html/.../single-2.php"); //destination to file where's author_id variables either.

function ajax_rental_add_to_cart()
{
    if ( STInput::request( 'action' ) == 'rental_add_cart' ) {
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "";
        $response['redirect'] = '';

        $author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() );
        $authlink = get_author_posts_url($author_id); 
        if ( $this->do_add_to_cart() ) {
            $response['redirect'] = $authlink;
            $response['status'] = 1;
            wp_send_json($response, 200);
        } else {
            $message = STTemplate::message();
            $response['message'] = $message;
            wp_send_json($response, 200);

        }
    }
}

    static function inst()
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

    STRental::inst()->init();
}

?>
```

Not sure is that `static function inst()` related, but pasting anyway. Problem is, on variable `$response['redirect'] = $authlink;` I should be redirected to h`ttps://example.com/author/author_id` , but I'm getting redirected only into `https://example.com/author/` 
It seems like controller file doesn't getting anyway author_id, maybe because after redirect it loosing author_id and that's why I'm not redirected to right way? Should I store author_id somehow and use it again in this file?

P.S. If I'm using same redirection in template file (not controller) - works perfectly, but then bypassing all date checks, so that's why I'm still messing up with controller file.

Comment: Looks like you are searching for global variables? But be warned, that might cause a lot of trouble as you will have problems finding the place where your variable was defined

Comment: You are also missing some code to make this a sensible example. I assume there is a class definition here somewhere

Comment: Using same like in template file, there’s just wrapped in echo <a href.., unless you hqve something else in your mind

Comment: stored with session variable and solved my issue. Thanks for your comments